# Merging fields Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a Form type like the following:

```
class TestType extends AbstractType{

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, $options){
     $builder->add('type', 'text');
     $builder->add('name', 'text');
   }
}
```

Now I want to create a Form Type that has two `TestType`s in it, but only has one `'type'` field which is used for both of the `TestType` fields used in it:

```
class DoubleTestType extends AbstractType{

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, $options){
     $builder->add('first', new TestType());
     $builder->add('second', new TestType()); // however this will create one type 'field' for each of the SubForms
   }
}
```

This approach will create two `TestType`s, each having an individual `'type'` field, but I want the `'type'` field shared between them. One approach is to to create a `'type'` field in `DoubleTestType`, and make the `type` field in `TestType`s hidden, and set their value using an event listener registered on the `DoubleTestType`. I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [form field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) instead of form type and then use it.

Or you can control field through the options parameters:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, $options){ 
    $type = isset($options['type']) ? $options['type'] : false; 
    if ($type) { 
        $builder->add('type', 'text');
    }
    $builder->add('name', 'text');
```

Then:

```
$builder->add('first', new TestType(array('type' => true)));
$builder->add('second', new TestType());
```

Comment: It is what I'm doing right now, the problem with this is, that the field `TestType` has implicit knowledge of it's parent form `DoubleTestType` which is not clean.

Comment: And what about using custom form field instead form type? (first part of my answer)